# Запуск фонового скрипта с индикацией завершения

Tags: php, yii

Нужно по нажатию кнопки передать параметр и начать работу скрипта в фоновом режиме. При этом надо показывать, что скрипт выполняется или отработал. Везде пишут через cron или как-то еще, но объясните, какими командами запустить крон, чтобы работало без расписания, как лучше отслеживать выполнение и как единоразово показать сообщение об успешной отработке скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, на клиенте:

1) по нажатию передаете параметр и тут же получаете в ответ id задачи;
 2) этот id передаете в запросе статуса задачи, в ответ получаете что-то из "в очереди", "выполняется: XX%", "выполенено". Дергаете это раз в секунду, например.

Сервер, получив задачу, ставит ее в очередь Gearman или просто сразу же запускает. В каком-то «общем» месте обновляет статус этой задачи, соотв. её id. Местом этим может быть БД, текстовый файл, кэш в памяти (APC, Memcache, Redis). Из этого же места скрипт, сообщающий о статусе выполнения, берет данные по id.

Answer (score 1):

То, что вы хотите сделать, делается через систему очередей.

[Очереди на Gearman и PHP](http://ruhighload.com/index.php/2010/07/09/gearman-%D0%B8-php-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/)